# Azure DevOps; Why are reviewers optional by default

Tags: azure-devops

When we create a new Pull Request in Azure DevOps, we've recently noticed that the Reviewer is Optional by default.

This has caused some confusion, as far as I recall, reviewers were always Required by default in the past.

Has this changed?

To make the Reviewer required, I know we can do this via the 'Add Required Reviewer' option but it would be nice if we could make the Reviewer Required by default...

[image]

Comment: Automatically include code reviewers should be the option you can choose, would this resolved your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recent changes you may be seeing, see the this [user voice request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/412370/allow-adding-required-reviewers-per-pull-request.html) and the blog post about the [new pull request experience](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-the-new-pull-request-experience-for-azure-repos/).

One thing we've done in the past to ensure a pull request always gets a review is [create teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) within the project [adding a set of users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-users-team-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) of which at least one will have to approve the pull request and then update the target branch policies to add the [team as a required reviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers).

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using branch policies, the bit thats called `add automatic reviewers`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers